# how to generate app-debug

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, apk

when I pressed run button I checked apk floder where app-debug-unaligned.apk generated but app-debug.apk not refreshed. I don't know what I did that this happened. check the date in picture[image]

EDIT: maybe people think I am lying but it's not true. maybe problem is in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.parsdroid.instagrameducation"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.5.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile files('src/main/libs/adad-2.9.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio, APK gets generated when we rebuild an application or run an application.

To get debug apk :

1. Rebuild your project or run your project
2. check your_app_location\app\build\outputs\apk

Edited :

Here in your gradle file you have used 'zipAlignEnabled' :

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
```

Problem is because of it. So please check how to use 'zipAlignEnabled' and try again.!!

Hope it will help.

Comment: I did the same just app-debug-unaligned generated.

Comment: @David : Clean your project and run again..!!

Comment: I did and now there is just one file in folder: app-debug-unaligned.apk

Comment: @David : Remove whole folder from there.And check after running application if it is generated again or not.

Comment: I did it too. Yes it's generated again with just unaligned apk. see the edit please

Comment: @  David : Remove debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled false
        } from gradle and try agian..!!

Comment: @ David  : There is issue with your debug flavour in gradle. I removed that and able to generate apk..!!

Comment: Thank you. it's just fault of "zipalign" and I must know how to use it. Please edit your answer with what happened in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Mamata Gelanee. You can simply remove **app-debug.apk** file from folder and clean the project and release new build again then check.